# Download large number of byte ranges from file using Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers

I've got a script that identifies byte ranges in a very large file that I'd like to download. I'm using Python's requests library to download the content, specifying the byte ranges of interest in the range header. Here's a simplified version of the code (without the logic that constructs the byte range string):

```py
import requests

URL = 'https://ncei.noaa.gov/data/rapid-refresh/access/historical/analysis/201602/20160217/rap_130_20160217_2200_000.grb2'

byte_range = '0-33510, 110484-147516, 219121-253904, 421175-454081, 685402-719065, 1039572-1076567, 1299982-1333158, 1398139-1429817, 1492109-1522167, \
1662765-1689414, 1870865-1896117, 2120537-2145725, 2301018-2335355, 2404445-2439381, 2511283-2547104, 2717931-2750956, 2971504-3001716, 3268591-3295610, \
3395201-3395200, 3395201-3461393, 3593639-3593638, 3593639-3659732, 3792859-3792858, 3792859-3859312, 4183232-4183231, 4183232-4245378, 4668359-4668358, \
4668359-4728450, 5283559-5283558, 5283559-5344745, 7251508-7317016, 7498496-7558460'

response = requests.get(URL, headers={"Range": "bytes={}".format(byte_range)})
print(response.headers)
```

As far as I can tell, this is a valid request and I don't get any errors. However, it downloads the entire file rather than the specified ranges. The output:

```
{'Date': 'Sat, 16 Oct 2021 15:26:17 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 18 Feb 2016 15:22:25 GMT', 'ETag': '"cfde25-52c0cef11064f"', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length': '13622821', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type', 'Connection': 'close'}
```

To debug, I tried shortening the number of byte ranges and that seemed to work. Seems like the max number of ranges for the request to return a subset of the file is in the low 20s.

```py
# Shorter list of byte ranges
URL = 'https://ncei.noaa.gov/data/rapid-refresh/access/historical/analysis/201602/20160217/rap_130_20160217_2200_000.grb2'

byte_range = '0-33510, 110484-147516, 219121-253904, 421175-454081, 685402-719065, 1039572-1076567, 1299982-1333158, 1398139-1429817, 1492109-1522167, \
1662765-1689414, 1870865-1896117, 2120537-2145725, 2301018-2335355, 2404445-2439381, 2511283-2547104, 2717931-2750956, 2971504-3001716, 3268591-3295610'

response = requests.get(URL, headers={"Range": "bytes={}".format(byte_range)})
print(response.headers)
```

In this case, the content type is a multipart byte range, as expected.

```
{'Date': 'Sat, 16 Oct 2021 15:26:41 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 18 Feb 2016 15:22:25 GMT', 'ETag': '"cfde25-52c0cef11064f"', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length': '577544', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/byteranges; boundary=ccc35e3764d85dea', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type', 'Connection': 'close'}
```

My question now is where's the limitation - is this an issue with requests, the server, or just an issue with HTTP headers? I could break this up into multiple requests, but I need to try to avoid spamming the server with a lot of requests near the same time (this byte range list could get pretty long depending on what I want from the file). If I had to break up the request, what's the most efficient way to do so? I really don't want to download more data than I need as these files can be quite large.

Comment: To eliminate `requests` as the source, you could make the same request using `curl` from the commandline with the byte ranges added e.g. `-H "Range: bytes=0-50, 100-150"`.